# Why does backbone filter collection fails when passing to view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have two methods to filter a collection:

Method 1: Using this method fails when I pass it to the view.

```
byCategory = @projects.byCategory(data)
```

Method 2: This method works very well.

```
byCategory = new App.Collections.Projects(@projects.byCategory(data))
```

Both methods works when I map byCategory and get the title:

```
byCategory.map (project) ->
  console.log project.get('title')
```

The second method works when I pass it to the view. But the first method fails:

```
view = new App.Views.ProjectsCarousel(collection: byCategory)
$('.slides').html(view.render().el);
```

My question is: Why? Why does the first fails when I pass it to the view, and why the second works?  The first one produces a error log: `TypeError: _ref is undefined`

#### Full code here:

Router

```
class App.Routers.PortfolioRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'

  index: ->
    controls = new App.Views.ProjectsControls({el: '#list', projects: new App.Collections.Projects()});
```

Collection

```
class App.Collections.Projects extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/de/projects'

  byCategory: (cat) ->
    return @where category: cat
```

Views

```
class App.Views.ProjectsControls extends Backbone.View

  events:
    'click a': 'selectCategory'

  initialize: (options) ->
    @projects = options.projects
    @projects.fetch()

  selectCategory: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    data = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-category')
    # This method fails when I pass it to the view
    # byCategory = @projects.byCategory(data)
    # This method works very well, why does it work and the previous no?
    byCategory = new App.Collections.Projects(@projects.byCategory(data))

    # it works with both methods
    byCategory.map (project) ->
      console.log project.get('title')

    view = new App.Views.ProjectsCarousel(collection: @projects)
    $('.slides').html(view.render().el);    



class App.Views.ProjectsCarousel extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['projects/carousel']

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(projects: @collection))
    this
```

Template

```
<% for project in @projects.models: %>
  <%= project.get('title') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please show the definition for `App.Collections.Project`? Specifically for `App.Collections.Project.byCategory()`

Comment: Also, how are your rendering the collection in `App.Views.ProjectsCarousel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

I assume that `@projects.byCategory(data)` returns an array of `Backbone.model`, while the view expects an instance of `Backbone.Collection`. In your view you're probably using `this.collection.models` for an iteration* and `.models` is a property that you certainly won't find in a plain array of `Backbone.model`.

> * The argument holds true if you're calling `collection.fetch()` or maybe even `.set()`, or any other `Backbone.Collection`, method

---

My intuition here (unless you say otherwise) is that

```
App.Collections.Projects.byCategory()
```

returns an array of `Backnone.model`, probably through a `.map()` or `.pluck()`. This assumption would answer your question and satisfy your `.map()` test.

### Question 1: Why does passing `byCategory = @projects.byCategory(data)` fail?

So if my assumption is correct, then the `byCategory` variable is nothing but a JavaScript Array of `Backbone.model`. This is not what Backbone expects when it uses the `Backbone.View.collection` property, for example when you do a `fetch`, or `set` or simply try to iterate through `collection.models` (and a simple array of `model` does not carry a `.models` prop).

### Question 2: Why does `.map()` always work?

The answer to this isn't obvious. Clearly `Backbone.collection.map` is going to work smoothly since `_.map()` is mixed into `Backbone.Collection` by default.

The reason `.map()` works on `byCategory === @projects.byCategory(data)` depends on two things. 
1. `byCategory` is an array, therefore, and I'm assuming you're using an ECMASCRIPT 5 compliant browser, `Array.prototype.map()` works. And it accepts the same chaining convention as does the mixed in `_.map()` and takes the same `Array` parameter as `_.map()`. So in effect, you could easily be fooled into thinking that you're using `Backbone.collection.map()`, while in fact you were using `Array.prototype.map()`.

The question remains, why did the `.get('title')` method in

```
console.log project.get('title')
```

work? Give the above, that's simple. Since you passed in an array of `Backone.model` to `Array.prototype.map()`, the argument in each iteration is `Backone.model`, which will happily accept `Backone.model.get()`.